# Netbeans, red text but no error

Tags: java, netbeans, dining-philosopher

I'm trying to implement a solution to the Dinning Philosophers. Not sure if I'm doing it right. My program isn't crashing but I am getting red text in the output, but there's no error code.

Example of the error:

at (package_name).Phil.getrightFork(Phil.java:70) 
the error alternatives between line 70, and 46 (which is the line that calls getrightFork)

I've already swapping getrightFork with getleftFork, but it always selects the rightFork as the error

Here's the code I'm using:
Custom Semaphore:

```
public class Semaphore {
public int value= 0 ;
public Semaphore(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}
public synchronized void up() { //notify must be syncrhonized
    value++;
    if (value > 0){
        this.notifyAll();
    }
}
public synchronized void down() throws InterruptedException {

    while (value <= 0){//Check if resource is avaiable, if not WAIT.
      this.wait();
    }
    value--; // Value is no longer negative
}}
```

main:

```
public class main {

private static final int N = 10000;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

    Phil[] phils = new Phil[N];
    Semaphore[] forks = new Semaphore[N];
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
      forks[i] = new Semaphore(1);
      phils[i] = new Phil(i, forks, N);
      phils[i].start();
    }
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
        phils[i].join();
    }
}}
```

Phil class:

```
 public class Phil extends Thread {

  Semaphore fork[]; 
  int phil, total, left, right;
  boolean leftFork = false, rightFork = false;

public Phil(int spot ,Semaphore[] s, int N){

   phil = spot;
   left = spot;
   fork = s;
   switch(spot){
       case 0: 
           right = N-1;
               break;
       default:
           right = spot - 1;
           break;
   }

}

public void run(){

    System.out.println("I am Phil " + phil + " my left fork is " + left + " my right fork is " + right);
 while(true){
 try {
  if (phil%2 == 0){
      Thread.sleep(10); // Let the odd Phils eat first
  }   
  getrightFork();

  if (rightFork){
      getleftFork();
  }

  if (leftFork && rightFork){
      eat();
      retleftFork();
      retrightFork();
  }
  Thread.sleep(10);

 } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

 }
}
}
void getleftFork() throws InterruptedException{
    fork[left].down();
    //System.out.println("I got my left fork!");
    leftFork = true;
}
 void getrightFork() throws InterruptedException{
    fork[right].down();
    //System.out.println("I got my right fork!");
    rightFork = true;
}

void retleftFork(){
    fork[left].up();
    leftFork = false;

}

void retrightFork(){
    fork[right].up();
    rightFork = false;
}

void eat(){
    System.out.println("Phil:" + phil + " ate");
}}
```

Comment: You're getting a `NullPointerException`?  The element in the array you are trying to access is `null`...Time to crack out the old debugger and step through your code...

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. 

How you figure out it was a NullPointerException though? whenever I ran it, it just pointed to a line.

Comment: It printed out `NullPointerException` and then dumped the stack trace.  You will need to walk back up the output to find the cause of the error (red lines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a `NullPointerException`. The element in the array you are trying to access is `null`.

This is caused by the fact that you `start` your `Phil` before the entire array is complete...

```
Phil[] phils = new Phil[N];
Semaphore[] forks = new Semaphore[N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    forks[i] = new Semaphore(1);
    phils[i] = new Phil(i, forks, N);
    // Phil is starting, but how many phils are there??
    phil.start();
}
```

Instead, try filling the array first and then starting them in a separate loop...

```
Phil[] phils = new Phil[N];
Semaphore[] forks = new Semaphore[N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    forks[i] = new Semaphore(1);
    phils[i] = new Phil(i, forks, N);
}
for (Phil phil : phils)  {
    phil.start();
}
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    phils[i].join();
}
```

If the solution requires that `Phil` be started as soon as they are created, then you need to change you checking code to handle the situation that the next element may be `null`